# php find a specify word in a specific column from stored proc sql server

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I'm kind of new in php and i'm searching a way to get some words from a specific column that i get from a sql server stored proc. These 'words' will me to use them as style for my css

Example : 
Column HTML_CODE has sometime 'bold', 'green' or something else. Sometime they are in the same column, not always in the same order. I don't know how to use them in my loop. See what i has until now :

```
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    //print_r( $row );  // debug code
    if ($row['HTML_CODE'] == 'BOLD(), Green()'){
        $couleur='green';
        $font= 'bold';
    }
    else {
        $couleur='black';
        $font= 'normal';
    } 
?>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:$font; color:$couleur;\">"; ?>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['Nom']); ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['Quantite']); ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['Montant']); if (is_numeric($row['Montant'])) {
                                      echo ' $';
                                    }?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['#GL']); ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['Debit']); if (is_numeric($row['Debit'])) {
                                      echo ' $';
                                    } ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo ($row['Credit']); if (is_numeric($row['Credit'])) {
                                      echo ' $';
                                    }?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

Comment: So, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes, using "strstr" as this : if( strstr($row['HTML_CODE'], "BOLD()")){
  $font= 'bold';
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if( strstr($row['HTML_CODE'], "BOLD()")){ $font= 'bold'; }